# Header/title disappears when UITableView is scrolled to the top

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, header, uikit

Working in Xamarin.ios (basically UIkit) and I have a UITableView with the Navigation title set. The title does not show when the table/screen is scrolled to the top. It only shows when you scroll down and it shows the title in the nav bar. Whats the best way to show the title when scrolled to the top but then have that title disappear behinf the nav bar title when scrolling?

pic 1: Should show title/header ontop of tableview, but it doesn't. It does show the right bar button item though

[image]

pic 2: when the user scrolls the tableview the navbar appears and it shows the title

[image]

It only shows the navbar title when scrolling through the tableview. But when not scrolling there is no "default" title.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I tried to clarify the question. Let me know if you still have questions

Comment: Why don't you simply set Nav Bar's title to "Tasks"? Then it should always be there...

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I've set "NavigationItem.Title = "Tasks;" in the ViewDidLoad() method and it still only shows up when scrolling

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint in that method, to verify that it ran?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve yep it runs. If I change the text from Tasks to something else it updates on the screen.

Comment: Could you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via github repo?